# Hide publish item from context menu

Tags: sxa

I am creating some scenarios where I need to hide `Publish Item` option from `Context menu` in Sitecore SXA.

[image]

I have tried in core database to hide it under this path:-

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default/Publish Item
```

However, I am not able to hide it. Is there any OOTB functionality to hide it from Context Item?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using to hide this from the menu will work but not for the admin user. It will work for all other users.

In the core database, if you go to this item and search for the field called "**Security**", you can open the assign security window using the **Assign Security** link on this field.

Here you can deny the read access on this item for all the roles that are assigned to this item. And it will hide it for all the users but not for the admin.

In your case, if you want it to work for other users then you can create a new role and deny the read permission for this item and then assign this role to this.

If you want to do it for all the users along with the admin then you need to think about some customization.

Here is one link that you can refer to.

https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2016/11/custom-sitecore-command-to-disable-or.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to create a new role and deny the read access of the publishing item from the `Core db` for the role.

1. Create a new role `DenyPublishingContextMenu`.
2. Switch to `Core db`.
3. Open the `Security editor`, Select the role `DenyPublishingContextMenu`, and explicitly deny the `read access`.
4. Apply `DenyPublishingContextMenu` to the user to prevent access from the context menu.

[image]

Hope it helps!